# Assembly x86 - Check for user input error

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having trouble with my program. I'm trying to have user input a number between 0-400 and it continues from there. Ive checked the cases of user input and it takes care of them all. The final part I'm missing and need help on is when the user enters something crazy like "2aaeios", it registers it as a "2" and takes the loop of comparing 2 to 0 and jg into "Case12"

How can I force user to enter a number from 0-400 and push forwards ErrorExit case otherwise?

```
INCLUDELIB C:\asmIrvine\Examples\Lib32\Irvine32_Library\Irvine32.lib
INCLUDE C:\asmIrvine\Examples\Lib32\Irvine32.inc

.data
ask_GPA BYTE "Please enter your GPA: ", 0
ask_UNITS BYTE "How many units are you taking? ", 0
case_noerror12 BYTE "Congratulations! Your GPA allows you to take up to 12 units.", 0
case_noerror16 BYTE "Congratulations! Your GPA allows you to take up to 16 units.", 0
case_noerror24 BYTE "Congratulations! Your GPA allows you to take up to 24 units. ", 0
invalid BYTE "Your entry is invalid. ", 0
quiter BYTE "You have exceeded the amount of tries. The program will now exit.", 0
GPA DWORD 0
units DWORD 0

.code
main PROC

mov ebx, 0
mov esi, 0
mov ecx, 0

L1:
mov edx, OFFSET ask_GPA
call WriteString
call readdec
mov GPA, eax
mov eax, 350

mov eax, GPA
cmp eax, 400            ;compare to 400
jg Errorexit            ;if higher than 400, errorexit
cmp eax, 350            ;compare to 350
jg Case24               ;if higher than 350, ask how many units to take
cmp eax, 250
jg Case16
cmp eax, 0
jg Case12
jmp Errorexit

Case24:                         
mov edx, OFFSET ask_UNITS       ;ask for unit 
call WriteString
call readdec
mov units, eax
cmp eax, 24                     
jg ErrorCounter                     ;if unit OVER 24, ERROR
cmp eax, 0
jl ErrorCounter                     ;if unit LESS than 0, ERROR
mov edx, OFFSET case_noerror24  ;else, successful message
call WriteString
jmp Quit

Case16:
mov edx, OFFSET ask_UNITS
call WriteString
call readdec
mov units, eax
cmp eax, 16
jg ErrorCounter
cmp eax, 0
jl ErrorCounter 
mov edx, OFFSET case_noerror16
call WriteString
jmp quit

Case12:
mov edx, OFFSET ask_UNITS
call WriteString
call readdec
mov units, eax
cmp eax, 12
jg Errorexit
cmp eax, 0
jl ErrorCounter
mov edx, OFFSET case_noerror12
call WriteString
jmp quit

ErrorCounter:
inc ecx
cmp ecx, 3
je quiterror
jmp L1

Errorexit:
mov edx, OFFSET invalid
call WriteString
jmp ErrorCounter

quiterror:
mov edx, OFFSET quiter
call WriteString
jmp quit

Quit:

exit    
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You might have to read user input as a string and check that there isn't non-numeric trailing garbage, if you want to reject that instead of silently taking the numeric part of strings.  Look at the Irvine32 docs for the input functions to see if `ReadDec` checks for error at all, and whether it consumes input to the end of a line or leaves it in the buffer.

Comment: You could have created [MCVE] just by creating short code doing [`call ReadDec`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readdec.htm) .. there was no need to add whole code. As you can read in the documentation, that function has no way to signal you invalid characters after the number. You will have to either rewrite the input to use different functions (string + own conversion to dec?), or live with it. (oh, for conversion there is `ParseDecimal32` available)

Comment: My bad on the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. First time posting. I'm also a fairly new with assembly language. What is the easiest and quick way you can suggest to do the check?

The ParseDecimal is confusing. I don't understand it.

Comment: first you read string input into memory (`ReadString`). Check returned size to be `> 0`, and that every inputted character is `('0' <= buffer[i] <= '9', i: 0..length-1)` -> if something of that fails, the input is invalid. If all does pass, you can call `ParseDecimal32` with that buffer to get unsigned integer value of the string (also check return flag for over-the-max error). Read the docs few times, and try to build just that tiny code reading string + checking + converting... in case you will fail hard, at least you will have minimal code for SO question. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Turns out, my professor accepted my method of catching the error. Since entering "2a" would register as "2." I just ask the user after they enter "2a" if they meant "2." If yes, press 1. If no, press 2. Coded response to cmp with 1. anything else results in jmping to the "then your input is invalid, reenter.."

She accepted for full points